# ES6 accessing variables outside of class

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

If I create a class called `Circle` :

```
class Circle{
  constructor(){
    this.cost = this.calculateCost()
  }
  showCosts(){
    console.log(l.findHeight(100));
  }
  calculateCost(){
    console.log(l.findHeight(100));
  }
}
```

and have two methods that try to access a variable called `l`, the `calculateCost` method does not work (it says that cannot findHeight of undefined) because it is getting accessed from the constructor.  But when I call

`l.showCosts()`

outside of the class, it gets called fine.  Why is this?  and how can I fix it?

```
let l = new Line();

class Line{
  findHeight(x){
    return x;
  }
}
```

Comment: `l` is your instance of the class. Use `this.findHeight` in the `calculateCost()` method and it should work

Comment: You need to use `this.` before class variables in JavaScript - like `self` in Python and unlike C++, Java and C# that have implicit `this`.

Comment: Also, to all the users downvoting - please consider close-voting this instead so that the OP can improve rather than downvoting which statistically doesn't help and just discourages OP.

Comment: @AbidHasan - Except there is no `.findHeight()` method on this object.  Can't really tell what the OP is attempting to do here.   Switching to `this` by itself will not be enough.  The OP has to show all the relevant code and describe the problem better.  Nothing we can do with what's here as this is an incomplete question.  Voting to close as "unclear what they're asking".

Comment: @jfriend00 This is obviously badly excerpted code - even the `l` isn't defined!

Comment: @jfriend00 But if he/she says l.showCosts() works outside the class, then obviously the class must have a findHeight defined in it somewhere, just not here

Comment: @AbidHasan - You're making wild guesses based on incomplete information.  Perhaps `l` is a different type of object entirely.  Who knows?  The point is that this question deserves to be closed as it stands now because it is incomplete and does not describe or show enough to be answered.

Comment: Are you actually attempting to define `l` _before_ `class Line`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because `l` variable isn't defined in the scope where it's used (the file where `Circle` class was defined). Even if it were defined, it's likely wouldn't work as expected - there can be multiple `Circle` instances, and they refer to current `l` variable.

This problem is addressed with [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) pattern.

The class can be refactored to use specific `l`:

```
class Circle{
  constructor(l){
    this.l = l;
    this.cost = this.calculateCost()
  }
  showCosts(){
    console.log(this.l.findHeight(100));
  }
  calculateCost(){
    console.log(this.l.findHeight(100));
  }
}

...

let l = new Line();
let circle = new Circle(l);
```